# How to flushright first column and flushleft last column in array in latex

Tags: align

I am quite a beginner in LaTex. I have the following codes:

`\begin{eqnarray}
            \therefore,d'(0)&=&0\notag\\
            \implies\big(q-\G(0)\big)\cdot\G'(0)&=&0\notag
        \end{eqnarray}`

And

`\[
            \begin{array}{cccc}
                \therefore,&d'(0)&=&0\notag\\
            \implies\big(q-\G(0)\big)\cdot\G'(0)&=&0\notag          \end{array}
        \]`

The first one does the job well but we cannot keep the '\therefore' and 'implies' in a separate column, whereas the second one makes the middle column center aligned. Can I have any one of the followings:

1. To add more columns in \eqnarray environment

Or,

2. To be able to align individual columns to my wish in \array environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How is defined `\GG`?

Comment: Do *not* use `eqnarray`: it produces bad spacing. Use `align` or `alignat` instead.

Comment: It should be noted that align etc. assumes every other & is a separate column and adds extra space for those &s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what you denote `\G` I added an own definition. It seems what you want can be obtained with the `alignat*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand*{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\def\G{\mathrm{G}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \eqmathbox{\therefore ,} & & d'(0) & =0 \\
 \eqmathbox{{}\implies{}} & & \bigl(q-\G(0)\bigr)\cdot\G'(0) & =0
 \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: Not sure a comma should be typed after `\therefore`.

Comment: Thanks much. Worked like a charm. I was using \G as shortcut to \gamma. Thanks again for pointing it out.